# IEnumerable<Model> in Web API returns The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WEB API. I created a Login Method in WEB API and debug it, it seems that there is no problem.
But after I published this project in IIS to check if it is working. Then this error occurs,
`The ObjectContent 1 type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8`

I really don't know what I am doing wrong because it seems to work while debugging.

I have this model to return after the Login Method is Successful.

//LOGIN MODEL

```
 public class LoginModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

//USER MODEL

```
 public class UserModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Juan ID")]
        public string juanID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string userName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Account Status")]
        public int accountStatus { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Account Type")]
        public int accountType { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Verified User")]
        public bool isVerified { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// User Information
        /// </summary>
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
        public string MidlleName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Age")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9] +", ErrorMessage = "Only half-width alphanumeric characters can be entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Image")]
        public string userImage { get; set; }

        public List<userContactInformation> ContactInformation { get; set; }

        ///Error Messaging
        ///
        public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    }
```

And this is the `LoginController: ApiController` of my project.

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
       UserModel userInformation = new UserModel();

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<UserModel> GetUserInformation(string username, string password)
        {
           
            LoginModel userCredentials = new LoginModel() { Username = username, Password = password };

            LogicInterface<UserLogicInput, SystemLogicResult> dbLogic = new LoginCheckLogic();

            UserLogicInput userInput = new UserLogicInput
            {
                [typeof(LoginModel).FullName] = userCredentials
            };

            SystemLogicResult dbResult = dbLogic.doProcess(userInput);

            if (dbResult.ResultCode != 0)
            {
                userInformation.ErrorCode = dbResult.ResultCode;
                userInformation.ErrorMessage = "User does not exist in the system Application";
                yield return userInformation;
            }
            else
            {
                userInformation = dbResult[typeof(UserModel).FullName] as UserModel;
                userInformation.ErrorCode = dbResult.ResultCode;
                userInformation.ErrorMessage = "Success!";                
                yield return userInformation;              
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the `LoginCheckLogic.cs`

```
public class LoginCheckLogic : AbstractDBLogic
    {
        protected override SystemLogicResult DBProcess(SqlConnection sqlConnection, UserLogicInput UserInput, SqlTransaction sqlTransaction)
        {
            LoginModel userInfo = UserInput[typeof(LoginModel).FullName] as LoginModel;

            if (userInfo == null || (userInfo.Email == null && userInfo.Username == null) || userInfo.Password == null) {
                
                return new SystemLogicResult() { 
                    ResultCode = SystemLogicResult.RESULT_CODE_ERR_DATA_NOT_EXIST                
                };
            }

            UserModel userInformation = new UserModel();
            
            if (userInfo.Email != null) {
                userInformation.Email = userInfo.Email;
            } else if (userInfo.Username != null) {
                userInformation.userName = userInfo.Username;
            }

            userInformation.Password = userInfo.Password;

            DBLoginProcess DBProcess = new DBLoginProcess();

            UserModel getAllUserInformation = DBProcess.getUserInformationUsingLoginCredentials(sqlConnection, userInformation, sqlTransaction);

            SystemLogicResult systemResult = new SystemLogicResult();

            if (getAllUserInformation == null) {
                systemResult.ResultCode = SystemLogicResult.RESULT_CODE_ERR_DATA_NOT_EXIST;
            } else {
                systemResult[typeof(UserModel).FullName] = getAllUserInformation;
            }

            return systemResult;
        }

        public string Encode_Password(string passWord) {

            try
            {
                if (passWord != "" || passWord != null)
                {
                    return Common.PasswordEncrypt.EncodeSHA256(passWord);
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return "";
            } 
          
        }
    }
```

And this is the DBLoginProcess

```
private UserModel retrievedUserInformation = null;
        private List<userContactInformation> userContactInformation = null;
        public UserModel getUserInformationUsingLoginCredentials(SqlConnection sqlConnection, UserModel userCredential , SqlTransaction sqlTransaction) {
            try {
                SqlCommand cmdQuery;
                if (userCredential.Email != null) {
                     cmdQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT juanID, Email, Username, userType, userStatus, isVerified FROM userLogin WHERE Email ='" + userCredential.Email + "' AND Password ='" + userCredential.Password + "'", sqlConnection);
                } else {
                     cmdQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT juanID, Email, Username, userType, userStatus, isVerified FROM userLogin WHERE Username ='" + userCredential.userName + "' AND Password ='" + userCredential.Password + "'", sqlConnection);
                }

                cmdQuery.Transaction = sqlTransaction;

                SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdQuery);

                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

                sqlAdapter.Fill(dTable);

                if (dTable.Rows.Count == 0 || dTable.Rows == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                retrievedUserInformation = new UserModel()
                {
                    juanID = dTable.Rows[0]["juanID"].ToString(),
                    Email = dTable.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString(),
                    userName = dTable.Rows[0]["Username"].ToString(),
                    accountType = (int)dTable.Rows[0]["userType"],
                    accountStatus = (int)dTable.Rows[0]["userStatus"],
                    Password = Common.PasswordEncrypt.EncodeSHA256(userCredential.Password),
                    isVerified = ((int)dTable.Rows[0]["userStatus"] == 1 ? true : false)
                };

                getUserInformationByJuanID(sqlConnection, sqlTransaction, ref retrievedUserInformation); //THIS IS ANOTHER METHOD TO GET THE INFORMATION OF THE USER INSIDE THE DATABASE.

                retrievedUserInformation.ContactInformation = GetUserContactInformationByJuanID(sqlConnection, sqlTransaction, retrievedUserInformation.juanID);  //THIS IS ANOTHER METHOD TO GET THE INFORMATION OF THE USER INSIDE THE DATABASE.

                return retrievedUserInformation;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Actually, this code I made is from MVC. I just used this code to create a WEB API and will consume it on my Android Application later after this API works.

Additional Information:

I already added the solutions I search from the internet. To add these two lines of code in my `Global.asax`. And not working at all.

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; //THIS
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter); //THIS
    }
```

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the two lines which you added it :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; //THIS
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter); //THIS
```

And try this one :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html") );
```

Or this one :

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new  QueryStringMapping("json", "true", "application/json"));
```

Comment: It still not working sir. But this time, the message is `The specified key did not exist in the directory.`

Comment: I don't understand what is the key exactly...? if you have any other details?
And what is the result exactly for the line code on the Debug :
SystemLogicResult dbResult = dbLogic.doProcess(userInput);   ??